# When Can the Tietze Extension Theorem give a Homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

Suppose we have a convex metric space $X$ with closed subspace $A$.  Then by the Tietze Extension Theorem, if $f: A \rightarrow X$ is any embedding then there is a continuous extension $\tilde{f}: X \rightarrow X$.

Under what conditions can we ensure that $\tilde{f}$ can be a homeomorphism?  Especially, I'm wondering if the following conditions are sufficient:
$$A \text{ is connected,}$$
$$dim(A) = dim(X) - 1, \text{and}$$
$$\partial(A) = \partial(f(A)) = \varnothing.$$

It seems strong enough in the examples I'm imagining, like the $xy$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I know that this statement is really a geometric/algebraic question in disguise, but I'm wondering if the convex geometry can be used with these assumptions to explicitly construct the Tietze function as a homeomorphism, without appealing to more advanced techniques.

Comment: I am trying to build up a quick-as-possible proof of the standard plane separation theorems, is why I'm asking.  The rectilinear JCT can be done pretty quick, but the Schoenflies rectilinear proof is very, very long.  The Annulus Theorem follows quickly after, tho, from the rectilinear version.  So if we can do rectilinear JCT+Annulus, but then a quick Schoenflies this way, it would make it possible to cover all three in an elementary way in just a couple lectures.

Comment: You should add the definition of a convex metric space.